# Sum, max and mean the values in a different column for each unique value in a column with Python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7],
                   'machine': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'b'],
                   'meters': [12, 9, 7, 9, 4, 9, 3, 7, 12, 9, 7, 9, 4, 9]},
)
```

[image]

With a function, for every unique value in 'machine' column, I want to print sentences like these automatically:

- For a machine sum is 39

  For a machine mean is 6.5

  For a machine max is 12
- For b machine sum is 50

  For b machine mean is 8.3

  For b machine max is 9
- For c machine sum is 12

  For c machine mean is 12

  For c machine max is 12
- For e machine sum is 9

  For e machine mean is 9

  For e machine max is 9

How can I write a definition basically?

Answer (score 5):

Group by `machine` and sum up `meters` for each group:

```
for m, s in df.groupby('machine')['meters'].sum().items():
    print(f'For {m} machine sum is {s}')
```

---

```
For a machine sum is 39
For b machine sum is 50
For c machine sum is 12
For e machine sum is 9
```

---

**UPD:** (due to extended requirements)

For a more extended aggregations use the following approach (with applied `.agg` function):

```
for m, d in df.groupby('machine')['meters'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'max']).to_dict('index').items():
    print(f'For {m} machine: sum is {d["sum"]}, '
          f'mean is {d["mean"]}, max is {d["max"]}')
```

---

```
For a machine: sum is 39, mean is 6.5, max is 12
For b machine: sum is 50, mean is 8.333333333333334, max is 9
For c machine: sum is 12, mean is 12.0, max is 12
For e machine: sum is 9, mean is 9.0, max is 9
```

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest. It is exactly what i mean (: if I want to print both total and average, do I have to write a new function (replacing the 'sum' part of this function with 'mean') or can I add to this function and solve it with a single function?

Comment: @volkan, update your main question with additional expected output

Comment: I updated the title for the extended question @RomanPerekhrest